# Operator overload but not viable

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I overloaded operator = for the class TextureImage in the class but the compiler keep saying no viable operator "=" .

```
    TextureImage& operator=(TextureImage i){
      this->x = i.getX();
      this->y = i.getY();
      this->n = i.getN();
      this->data = i.getData();
      return *this;
    }
```

If I add `const` to the function the compiler says I can't assign to non-static data member within const member function.

So how to overloaded operator = here

Comment: It should accept a const reference to the object being copied `=(TextureImage const & i)`.

Comment: @VTT That wouldn't matter much, but yes that's the canonical form.

Comment: Copy&paste the complete message!

Comment: If any of `x`, `y`, `n`, or `data` are pointers or contain a resource that is not trivially duplicated you will have a logic error to deal with once the program compiles. If not, it is possible that you don't need an assignment operator at all (see [The Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)). [The Copy and Swap Idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) may assist you in writing future assignment operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly don't want to have the assignment operator overloaded as `const` member function. If you insist, make all the member variables `mutable`.

The canonical form looks like

```
TextureImage& operator=(const TextureImage& i) {
   x = i.x;
   y = i.y;
   n = i.n;
   data = i.data;
   return *this;
}
```

Note you don't need to use the getters there.

If there's nothing more to do there, you don't need to implement your own assignment operator, since the compiler already generates that code automatically or on demand

```
TextureImage& operator=(const TextureImage& i) = default;
```

---

Though I suspect `data` needs some more special handling, since it sounds that is kind of array or pointer member variable.

In this case I would recommend you use a `std::array` or `std::vector` as data member and stick with the default implementation.

Comment: I made it muatble but it keep saying the overloaded = is not viable

Comment: If it was in this "canonical form", you would not need to write it in the first place.

Comment: @JOYD No, mentioning `mutual` was more a sophisticated joke. Provide the implementation as I've shown in my answer please.

Comment: @Neil Yes, it's already generated by the compiler automatically. Or did you mean `&&` move?

Comment: I'm saying that if that is all your copy assignment operator does, you should not write your own implementation of it.

Comment: @Neil I understood that.

Comment: I'm sure _you_ do, but I feel your answer may confuse the OP.

Comment: @Neil I tried to add more info about that. Though I'm not so sure about solving the _confusion_ ;-).

Comment: Sorry I am late, but I finally found the problem. It seems that I was calling this function from a const function. Thank you for helping me!